# Dice Rolling Probability in using R studio

Tags: rstudio, difference, dice

So I want to know how to set this up to get the correct answer in R.

If you roll two standard 6-sided die, estimate the probability that the difference between them is 3, 4, or 5 (and not 0, 1, or 2).

I know how to set up the basic model of finding a sum but am not sure on how I can find the difference.  PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: This is a simulation exercise which I'm trying to find the probability of rolling two dice and the difference of the rolls being 3, 4, or 5.  I do not know how to set up this in R.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you are doing. I guess you simulate the die rolls? So you have a data.frame with two columns, each containing the rolls of one die?
Like this:

```
die_rolls <- data.frame(die1 = c(1, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4), die2 = c(3, 5, 6, 2, 1, 1))
```

Then you could create a new column that calculates the difference. And then uses the absolute value of it, i.e. you won't have negative values.

```
die_rolls$difference <- abs(die_rolls$die1 - die_rolls$die2)
```

Comment: This is a simulation exercise which I'm trying to find the probability of rolling two dice and the difference of the rolls being 3, 4, or 5.  I do not know how to set up this in R.

Comment: But you have already written some code, right? Something to start with? Because you wrote "I know how to set up the basic model of finding a sum". It would be good to know what you've got so far and what is left. And if the code I showed you is what you are looking for or not at all.